# Does Saxon have a fast compile mode?

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

We generally are making a large number of XPath queries where almost none of them repeat. So each query is compiled, executed, and then thrown out.

Is there a mode in Saxon we should set telling it to build the compiled queries for one-time use that will then be faster when used in this mode?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

It's an excellent question, because Saxon does tend to invest rather too much effort into optimizing queries to get the fastest possible run-time execution, and it's not uncommon to spend 100ms compiling and then 1ms executing the result.

Switching off all optimization using -opt:0 is the only real option available. It typically cuts out 30% of the compile time cost (though of course that's highly variable).

On the XSLT side, Saxon-EE 9.8 introduces just-in-time compilation of template rules, so if you're applying a vast stylesheet like DocBook to a small instance document, we now only compile the template rules that you actually use. In that scenario, this can make a big difference.

But there's no equivalent at the XPath level.

We've been investigating your specific use case and our initial analysis is here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3843. As so often happens with performance, the devil is in the detail, and problems with poor performance (and their solutions) are often very specific to the particular processing scenario.

Comment: Is there an API call to turn off the optimizations? For XPath? Or is it command line & XQuery only? thanks - dave

Comment: Optimization level can only be controlled at Processor/Configuration level using setConfigurationProperty().

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the list of config features](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/configuration/config-features.html), there's nothing quite like you describe. The closest thing would be `OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL`:

> this feature allows optimization to be suppressed in cases where
>   reducing compile time is important

but I haven't used it so your mileage may vary. You can disable optimisations selectively, so it may take a good deal of experimentation to find the sweet spot.